# iRedMail SSL using Lets Encrypt certbot-auto

Tags: ssl, nginx, server, lets-encrypt, iredmail

I'm setting up a mail server using iRedMail and have everything installed and running. Now trying to change the self signed certificate for a Lets Encrypt using the certbot-auto client. I have added

```
location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
}
```

into /etc/nginx/templates/misc.tmpl like this

```
location ~ /.well-known {
    allow all;
}

# Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess.
#location ~ /\. { deny all; }

# Handling noisy messages
location = ^/favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = ^/robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
```

However when I restart nginx and browse to the URL, I get a 404, and certbot-auto also reports a 404.

I've placed it above the rule to restrict access to hidden files, so this should work.

Any ideas would be massively appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: I solved my problem... I was entering the wrong domain name. Very silly.

Answer (score 1):

```
location /.well-known {
alias /opt/www/iredadmin/.well-known/;
}
```